# Alternative to pyspark.sql.functions.filter for older versions

Tags: python, pyspark, module, version

Problem:

I have a dataframe df and a column `LongColumn` that that has rows like this:

```
FIRST_WORD.ABC.approved.Address.Street.Phone.Email.Category1.Beta.MyResults.New
FIRST_WORD.DEF.Address.Street.Phone.Email.Category2.Alpha.MyResults.New
FIRST_WORD.ABC.Address.Street.Phone.Email.Category6.Gamma.MyResults.New
FIRST_WORD.GHI.approved.Address.Street.Phone.Email.Category1.Alpha.MyResults.New
```

I need an extra column: `Status` which contains `approved` if the word `approved` appears there, and `unapproved` if it does not , and `Code` which contains the three letters on the second position.

The three latin letters are always on the same position (if I take it top-down), but no matter the direction, the `approved` is a problem.

Expected output (assuming I drop the `LongColumn` whose values are now arrays):

```
   Code     Status        
    ABC      approved     
    DEF      unapproved   
    ABC      unapproved   
    GHI      approved
```

Solution:

from pyspark.sql import functions as F

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=schema)
out_df=df.withColumn('LongColumn', F.split('LongColumn', '\.'))\
.withColumn('status_val',F.array(F.lit("approved"),F.lit("unapproved")))\
.withColumn("status",F.filter("LongColumn",lambda x:F.array_contains("status_val",x)))\
.withColumn("status",F.when(F.size(F.col("status"))==1,F.col("status")[0]).otherwise(F.lit("unapproved")))\
.drop("status_val")
```

The problem is, I get `AttributeError: module 'pyspark.sql.functions' has no attribute 'filter'`. I assume it is because of the version, but I do not have any possibility to increase the version. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

data_list = ["FIRST_WORD.ABC.approved.Address.Street.Phone.Email.Category1.Beta.MyResults.New",
        "FIRST_WORD.DEF.Address.Street.Phone.Email.Category2.Alpha.MyResults.New",
        "FIRST_WORD.ABC.Address.Street.Phone.Email.Category6.Gamma.MyResults.New",
        "FIRST_WORD.GHI.approved.Address.Street.Phone.Email.Category1.Alpha.MyResults.New"]


df = spark.createDataFrame(data_list, StringType()).toDF("LongColumn")

out_df= (
    df
    .withColumn('Code', F.substring(F.col('LongColumn'), 12, 3))
    .withColumn('Status'
                , F.when(F.col('LongColumn').rlike('approved'),
                         'approved').otherwise('unapproved')
               )
    .drop("LongColumn")
    )
```

Result:

| Code | Status |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | approved |
| DEF | unapproved |
| ABC | unapproved |
| GHI | approved |

Answer (score 0):

The [`filter`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.filter.html#pyspark-sql-functions-filter) SQL function can also be used within `expr()` for versions that do not support it.

```py
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('status', 
               func.expr('filter(longcolumn, x -> array_contains(status_val, x))')
               )
```